# type conversion between pointers. Wrong print

Tags: c

The program is written in language C.

We ascertain that the values contained in the variables i and f have the same sequence of bits. Now go to line 63 of the program.
I create the variables ui and uf of type unsigned int.
I assign to ui the value of i converted to unsigned int.
I assign to uf the value of f converted to unsigned int.
MY QUESTION is: why when I print the contents of ui and uf I get two different values? (ui = 3281948672
uf = 4294966979). Considering that the values contained in i and f have the same binary representation, shouldn't the printing of ui and uf give me the same value? That is 3281948672.
it's strange, because when I print the contents of *ipi and *ipf, which point to i and f, they give me the same result (*ipi = 3281948672
*ipf = 3281948672). HELP ME!

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

float f = -317.125;
int i = -1013018624;

printf("Value : %f  %d\n",f,i);
printf("Indexs: %p  %p\n",&f,&i);

if(i == f)
{
    printf("equals\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Differents\n");
}

float* pf = &f;
int* pi = &i;

printf("float *pt %p, int *pi  %p\n",pf,pi);

if(*pi == *pf)
{
    printf("*pt and *pi equals\n");
}
else
{
    printf("differents\n");
}

void* vpf = &f;
void* vpi = &i;


unsigned int *ipf = (unsigned int *)vpf;
unsigned int *ipi = (unsigned int *)vpi;


if(*ipf == *ipi)
{
    printf("*ipf e *ipi are equals why the bits contained in the pointed memory areas are the same\n");
}
else
{
    printf("differents\n");
}

printf("*ipi = %u\n",*ipi);
printf("*ipf = %u\n",*ipf);
printf("*ipi in hex = %08X\n",*ipi);
printf("*ipf in hex = %08X\n\n\n",*ipf);






unsigned int ui,uf;
ui = (unsigned int)i;
uf = (unsigned int)f;
printf("ui = %u\n",ui);
printf("uf = %u",uf);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: while you do not cast the binary representation is not relevant when comparing an integer and a float => their value are different

Comment: the cast `(unsigned int)f`  keeps the value ... the aliasing `*(unsigned int*)&f` keeps the bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, conversion from a floating point type to an integral type is *not* a bit-for-bit conversion. So, even though `i` and `f` are bit-for-bit identical, they are not converted to `unsigned int` in an identical way. What you see is expected behavior.